# Deploy personal programs and scripts

Tags: software-installation, libraries, binary, deployment

I have a `git` project containing useful programs and scripts. Hierarchy looks like this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/myaccount/myutils.git

$ tree myutils
.
├── bash
│   ├── do-this.sh
│   ├── do-that.sh
│   ├── functions-to-source.sh  # Contains useful functions that will be sourced by other scripts.
│   ├── tests
│   │   ├── bin
│   │   └── command.ext1.ext2.ext3
│   └── todo
├── python
│   ├── notes
│   └── package1
│       ├── module1.py
│       └── module2.py
└── c
    ├── bin
    ├── build
    ├── doc
    ├── include
    ├── lib
    ├── Makefile
    ├── src
    └── test
```

We could also view each folder as a project. How should I install my files in `/usr/local`? I want to make them general purpose tools to be installed in `/usr/local`. I read that we should put in `/usr/local/src` what has to be compiled. Here only C project needs to be compiled, so do I copy the content of each subfolder (bin, lib, src) in the corresponding subfolders of `/usr/local`? What about scripts that need no compilation. Should I copy each script in `/usr/local/bin`? Or make a symbolic link to them? What about the whole project, should it be moved in some specific folders? I'd like to know more about good (best?) deployment practice.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [GNU Stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) to create a hierarchy under the `/opt` directory for any site-specific software (see [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard), although some sites use `/sw` instead).  That way, your stuff would

1. [using `/opt`] ... not collide with anything installed by any package manager.
2. [using `stow`] ... be *really* easy to install/uninstall.

For `stow`, create the directory `/opt/stow`.

Beneath that, create a complete sub-hierarchy for each individual project, i.e.

- `/opt/stow/project-1/{bin,lib,man}`
- `/opt/stow/project-2/bin`
- `/opt/stow/project-3/{bin,fun,share/examples}` (`fun` for sourcable shell code with shell functions)
- etc.

Don't put C source code there, only things that are needed to use the tools.

Then:

```
$ cd /opt/stow
$ stow project-1
$ stow project-2
$ stow project-3
```

Each invocation of `stow` will populate the directory `/opt` with symbolic links to the correct places, so that your executables from e.g. `/opt/stow/project-1/bin` *and* `/opt/stow/project-2/bin` are easily accessible in `/opt/bin`.

Then add `/opt/bin` to your `PATH` and you're set.

To *uninstall* e.g. `project-1` from `/opt`:

```
$ cd /opt/stow
$ stow -D project-1
```

This will remove all links from the `/opt` hierarchy that points into `/opt/stow/project-1`, but leave the contents of `/opt/stow/project-1` intact.

You could then, if you had a new version of your first project:

```
$ # (having un-stowed project-1, and still in /opt/stow ...)
$ mv project-1 project-1.old
$ cp $HOME/path/project-1 ./
$ stow project-1
```

Use `stow` with the `-v` flag to see what's actually happening.

Basically, GNU Stow makes it easy to keep separate installations of applications *separate*.  I use it all the time for code I compile and install under `$HOME/local` (by using `--prefix` with `./configure` for example).  Makes it easier to uninstall things.